# Another Riley? Yep

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix helps you understand,
>
> My infix falls,
>
> My suffix cleans,
>
> I condition your thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My prefix helps you understand,

> brain-. you would have a hard time understanding without a brain.

My infix falls,

> -rain-. rain is falling water.

My suffix cleans,

> -wash. by washing something, you clean it.

I condition your thinking.

> brainwash. thought conditioning is the definition of brainwashing.

Comment: Yep that is the answer! :D